# Linking function output to GUI in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hi I am trying to write a simple program that while working in the background looks for how long a specific executable is working. This bit works in the shell of the IDE however I don't know how to connect the shells output to the GUI so that it refreshes and shows the time in seconds that a program is working for.

[I have tried StringVar but it failed]

If someone would help it would be lovely

Below is the code which as stated works only partially:

```
import time
from tkinter import * # Another GUI-Framework is PYQT5
import wmi
import sys

c = wmi.WMI()
Task_List = []


class AppButtons:
    # A variable and a List for the gatering of currently running processes

    def __init__(self, master):
        main_frame = Frame(master)
        main_frame.pack()

        '''
        #Program title
        self.Label = Label(main_frame, text='The time monitoring app')
        self.Label.config(font=("Courier", 30), anchor=CENTER)
        self.Label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        '''


        # Program start
        self.strat_timer = Button(main_frame, text='Beggin the app running time monitoring!!!', command=self.main_timer)
        self.strat_timer.config(font=("Courier", 12))
        self.strat_timer.grid(row=1, column=0,pady=10, sticky=E+W) # pady and padx add space btw the widgets in the x and y directions corespondingly

        # Program termination
        self.end_timer = Button(main_frame, text='Terminate the app timmer', command=self.timer_kill)
        self.end_timer.config(font=("Courier", 12))
        self.end_timer.grid(row=1, column=1,pady=10, sticky=E+W)

        # Output description
        self.time_overwatch_label1 = Label(main_frame, bg='red' ,width=60, height=1 , text='Program: WorldOfTanks.exe | Running time:')
        self.time_overwatch_label1.grid(row=2, column=0,)

        self.time_overwatch_label2 = Label(main_frame, bg='Yellow',width=60, height=1 , text='Program: chrome.exe | Running time:')
        self.time_overwatch_label2.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.time_overwatch_label3 = Label(main_frame, bg='red',width=60, height=1 , text='Program: pycharm64.exe | Running time:')
        self.time_overwatch_label3.grid(row=4, column=0)


        # Output part
        self.output1 = Label(main_frame, bg='red' ,width=60, height=1, text=self.main_timer)
        self.output1.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.output2 = Text(main_frame, bg='Yellow', width=60, height=1)
        self.output2.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.output3 = Text(main_frame, bg='red', width=60, height=1)
        self.output3.grid(row=4, column=1)

    # gives the list of currently running processes using the WMI library
    def running_tasks(self):
        Task_List.clear()
        for process in c.Win32_Process():
            Task_List.append(process.Name)
        return Task_List

    def program_search(self):
        self.running_tasks()
        if any('WorldOfTanks.exe' in s for s in Task_List):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # Main fuction which is responsible for the output of the timmer (in this example of WorldOfTanks.exe)
    # This fuction cosists of "running_tasks" and "task_search". It should be called from the GUI window
    def main_timer(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        while True:
            if self.program_search() is True:
                print('WoT is Running for', "--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
                continue
            if time.time() - start_time < 21:
                print("World of Tanks wasn't running")
                break
            if self.program_search() is False:
                print('WorldOfTanks.exe was running for', "--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
                break


    def timer_kill(self):
        sys.exit()


root = Tk()

# Title of the window is displayed on the uppermost bar
root.title("The Time Monitoring App")

# Initializes the class
b = AppButtons(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The most sensible approach would be to create three `StringVar()` for the three running times and linking them to the labels.
At each iteration of the loop (which might be less demanding if you included a `time.sleep(.5)` to wait for half a second before running it again), update all of the string variables.

Creating and linking the string variables:

```
    self.t1 = StringVar()
    self.t1.set("No time recorded for WoT") ## Set to no output before the button is pressed

    self.output1 = Label(main_frame, bg='red' ,width=60, height=1, textvariable=self.t1)
    self.output1.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Updating their values:

```
def main_timer(self):
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if self.program_search() is True:
            self.t1.set('WoT is Running for', "--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
            continue
        if time.time() - start_time < 21:
            self.t1.set("World of Tanks wasn't running")
            break
        if self.program_search() is False:
            self.t1.set('WorldOfTanks.exe was running for', "--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
            break
```

Whenever you change the value of `self.t1` in the method `.main_timer()`, the label will be updated as it is directly linked to this StringVar.
**Important**: The text of the label has to be set using `textvariable`, not `text`, if you want it to change automatically.

Comment: Are you aware that a `StringVar` isn't necessary? You can use it, but you can also directly change the text of a label without it. In this case the `StringVar` adds overhead without adding any additional benefit.

Comment: OK now I see how this is supposed to be done, thanks to both of You. Now I understand the StringVar method (though I don't know how should I do it without it as Bryan Oakley suggested,, but i guess I don't need it)

Comment: @Brian: No, I was actually unaware of that. I thought, the .set() method was required to update all widgets that use this textvariable. But if it's not necessary, I have quite a lot of code cleaning to do :)

Comment: @MartinWettstein I don't only have code cleaning to do but also quite some learning. I have implemnted what You have written, but somehow for some unknown reasen the code works but it dosn't update this value in the GUI [BUT IN A DEBUGGER IT IS OBVIOUS THAT THE VALUE T1 GETS UPDATED !!!] do You have any idea why ? (I have read that it might be somehow bugged because of the loop). I will put the code in a separate anwser.